# How to get overlay to fill scrollable parent using pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, overlay

Here's a simple example:

```
<div class = "has-scrollbar">
    <div class = "long"></div>
    <div class = "overlay"></div>
</div>

.has-scrollbar {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
}

.long {
    height: 200px;
    width: 50px;
    background: blue;
}

.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XtLJ7/1/)

The red overlay should completely fill the parent container. The height of `.long` is not known in advance. The `.has-scrollbar` div should still be scrollable (and not covered).

Any solution using `position: fixed` on `.overlay` will not likely work. The real-world scenario is far more complex. Consider the position of `.has-scrollbar` within the `body` to also not be known in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you don't know about `long`, but seems like you do control `has-scrollbar`, so you can make `overlay` fixed and position it in the same place as `has-scrollbar`:

```
.overlay {
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 8px; /* just to compensate for body margin in the example */
    pointer-events: none; /* mouse events will pass through */
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/XtLJ7/6/)

Comment: I forgot to add one more constraint to the problem - the .has-scrollbar div should still be scrollable (and not covered). Thanks though!

Comment: I added one css rule to pass through mouse events :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the overly to block interaction with the content underneath.

Comment: The solution I ended up going with used `position: fixed`, so you get the points :)